# Converting ZipOutputStream to ZipInputStream

Tags: java, file-io, zipoutputstream

I am creating a ZipOutputStream and adding files to it this is being done in memory , later I want to be able to get/read files from this. I have tried multiple permutations and combinations but am not able to get it done.
I know if I use FileOutpuStream and attach a physical file to it I will be able to use it but I am not allowed to create physical file.

Current Code:-

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos);
 ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(“Temp.txt”);
 zos.putNextEntry(ze);
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Test/File1.txt");
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
 int len;
 while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
   //System.out.println(new String(buffer));
    zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track! To read the file back, simply use:

```
byte[] zipBytes = bos.toByteArray();
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(zipBytes);
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(bis);
```